# En variable, asignar valor, cambiarlo en una funcion y pasar el valor cambiado a otra

Tags: java, funciones, variables-globales, bucles

Ire al grano; estoy haciendo algo como esto:

```
public class clase{//clase principal
int valor;//variable global

if (post.containsKey("xempieza")) { 
            if(valida()){
            bit.bitHtml = recibedato(); //bit.bitHtml obtiene y añade el html que previamente existia. 
            return;
            }
        }

 public string enviadato(){
  String html="<cosas html>;
  Connection conn=null;
  PreparedStatement ps=null;
  ResultSet rs=null;

  try{
  conn=*base datos*;
  ps=conn.preparestatement(select valor, nombre from miTabla)//hago consulta y busco datos.
  rs=ps.executeQuery();

  int fila=0;
  while (rs.next)){
    valor=rs.getInt("valor");//Aqui empiezo; quiero darle el valor extraido de mi consulta a mi variable global.  
    html+="<input type='submit' value='"+rs.getString("nombre")+"' name='xempieza'>"
        +"<input type='hidden' value='"+ rs.getInt("valor") + "' name='xvalor'>";//el principal inconveniente es que traigo varios valores ,para que cree varios input con los datos obtenidos, cada uno con su identificador(valor).
  }
  }catch (Exception e) {}
  return html;
 }

 public boolean valida(){
        String validavalor;
        if (post.containsKey("xvalor")){ //obtiene el hidden
            validavalor=((String[]) post.get("xvalor"))[0].trim(); 
            valor=Integer.parseInt(validavalor); //convierte la cadena obtenida a int
        }
        return true;
    }



 public string recibedato(){
  String html="<otra pagina html>";
  /*coneccion, rs y ps*/
  ...
  ps=conn.prepareStatement("select datos from mitabla2 where datosid=?");
  ps.setInt(valor);
  rs=ps.executeQuery();
  if(rs.next)){
   html+="<iframe src='"+rs.getString("datos")+"'>"; //sin embargo, al obtener la variable global, el valor de esta es 1, sin importar en cual de los input haya clickeado, aun cuando cada uno tiene un identificador(valor) diferente. 
  }
 }
}
```

/*Pues eso. A grandes rasgos, quiero obtener el identificador generado de un while, asignarlo a una variable global, y que el valor sea pasado a otra funcion sin ser modificado. 
Aqui tengo dos dudas; la primera es como hacer que el valor pase de una funcion otra sin que pierda el valor asignado en la primer funcion.
La segunda, es como saber si el problema viene en mi WHILE, ya que como son botones generados , no se si al cambiar de funcion, estos se pierden y asignan un valor generico, o el primer valor obtenido del while....
Espero darme a entender.*/

EDIT:

Ya lo he estado estudiando, y el problema reside en mi while. Aqui es donde estaria solicitanto su ayuda. Como habia dicho, mis botones se generan de acuerdo a los datos obtenidos del sql. Sin embargo, al pasar el get("xvalor"), y como viene en un array, este solo obtiene el de la posicion 0 ([0].trim()). Lo que me gustaria saber es como puedo hacer para que cuando el usuario haga click en algun boton este me envie la posicion del boton ([0 o 1 o 2 oetc].trim()).
Nuevamente, espero su ayuda, Saludos!